# Generate a postback after some time has passed

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, postback

Is it possible to generate a postback after some time has passed?
Let's say: I have some text that the user has to type in a text box. If he doesn't type anything in the next 1 minute, the page should be refreshed showing a warning or something

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)  What you're probably looking for is the results from a search on "timeout" and "automatic postback."

Comment: @TLS - I actually used 'javascript timer postback', but adding auto would have been a good choice as well.

Answer (score 2):

This article should help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12293/Auto-postback-in-ASP-NET

However, you'll have to integrate your own business logic with regards to posting back, or not because you failed to include your source code.  BUT, this example includes a `StopTheClock()` method, so you'll likely want some kind of "OnChange" event attached to the textbox that stops the clock when the value is not empty.

Another approach, would be to check the value of the textbox after each tick (1 second in this case) and just before postback (form.submit) and then simply stop the timer if the textbox.value is not empty.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
// Script to generate an automatic postBack to the server
var secs
var timerID = null
var timerRunning = false
var delay = 1000
function InitializeTimer()
{
    // Set the length of the timer,
     // in seconds. Your choise
    secs = 5

    StopTheClock()
    StartTheTimer()
}
function StopTheClock()
{
    if(timerRunning)
        clearTimeout(timerID)
    timerRunning = false
}
function StartTheTimer()
{
    if (secs==0)
    {
        StopTheClock()

        //Generate a Postback to the server
        document.forms[0].submit()  

    }
    else
    {
        secs = secs - 1
        timerRunning = true
        timerID = self.setTimeout("StartTheTimer()", delay)
    }
}
//-->
</script>


<body onload="InitializeTimer()">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div>
       The time is:   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly advise AGAINST an approach like this. All you need is to notify a user or maybe modify a part of the page. Complete postback is really a waste. Instead, I'd suggest to use Ajax. Maybe add a timer using javascript, listen to desired events and raise ajax requests as needed.

Comment: I agree!  A client-side warning would be better - and an AJAX call if needed.  Why not post an example of this?

Comment: @ChrisGessler, two reasons - 1.) have shortage of time at the moment 2.) OP obviously didn't use Google to do at least the basic research, because otherwise the question would be much more specific. If I don't know which part is he having problems with, I can't provide the whole solution. You gave him something, Rab gave him something and if he combines these three answers together, he should be fine. If not, I'm sure he'll complete his question. Currently he asks a single thing - "is this possible"? The answer is a simple "Yes" :)